# Create a list from searching a text file for [ ]

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to create a list from a text file that I am reading into Python. The text file contains a bunch of square brackets throughout the file [some text here]. What I am trying to do is first count how many of those square bracket pairings I have [] and then add whatever text is inside of them into a list.

Here is a super simplified version of the text file I am trying to use with the brackets:

```
"[name] is going to the store! It's going to be at [place] on [day-of-the-week]."
```

Here is what I have:

```
bracket_counter = 0

file_name = "example.txt"
readFile = open(file_name)
text_lines = readFile.readlines()

for line in text_lines:
    val = line.split('[', 1)[1].split(']')[0]
    print(val)
    if line has [ and ]:
        bracket_counter += 1
```

I'm super new to Python. I don't know if I should be using regular expressions for this or if that is overcomplicating things.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look into opening your file using a context manager or at least remember to close the file after using it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can of course use regular expressions for that. In the following example, you're extracting all content within square brackets and store them in the variable `words`.

```py
words = re.findall(r'\[([^\]]+)\]', line)
```

Don't forget to `import re` at the top of your program.

**Explanation of the regex**:

- `\[` and `\]` match square brackets. As these are used in regex as well, you have to escape them with a backslash
- `(...)` is a capturing group, all regex parts within normal brackets will be returned as a finding (for e.g. in the list `words`)
- `[^\]]+` will match all characters except the `]`

To put it all together:

This regex looks for an opening square bracket, then matches all characters until a closing square bracket appears and returns the matches within a list.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to include the opening bracket in your `[^...]` expression ? I have the same solution but with `[^\[\]]+` . With that you make really sure only everything inside the most inner opening and closing brackets get captured

Comment: Probably yes, I excluded them to avoid having them returned to `words`. If you (@icekomo) don't need the brackets and want to use the expression suggested by @Rabinzel, simply strip the brackets off, replace them or use string slicing for that.

Comment: I think you mean something different. For example the string `"[[name] ..."`: in your result would appear as `[name` because between the two brackets you only exclude the closing bracket, but you only want `name` as a result.

Comment: Okay, now I get your point. But if values are nested, the whole regex won't work as it's written down above. With the regex you came up with, something like `"[[name] is] ..."` will not work.

Comment: it would just always match only the most inner words which are between an opening and closing bracket. `"[[name] is] ..."` also results in `name` . tbh, your pattern works perfect on this question, I just thought with adding that you cover this special case without making a big difference... but it isn't really necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a lonely soul out there like me who wondered how this could be done without using regex, I guess this could be a solution also:

```
results = []
with open("example.txt") as read:
    for line in read:
        start = None; end = None
        for i,v in enumerate(line):
            if v == "[": start = i
            if v == "]": end = i
            if start is not None and end is not None:
                results.append(line[start+1:end])
                start = None; end = None

print(results)
```

Result:

```
['name', 'place', 'day-of-the-week']
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a `has` keyword.
You're probably looking for something like:

```
('[' in line) or (']' in line)
```

which will evaluate to True if the line includes [ or ].